# Launch GUI app from udev rule

Tags: usb, udev, usb-device

I am trying to launch a GUI app upon plugging in a certain USB device.
The udev rule gets triggered, but the app does appear on my screen.
Running the script from another TTY makes the app open in my graphical environment.
I can also confirm that the rule is getting triggered by appending a date to a file from the rule.

/etc/udev/rules.d/99-betaflight.rules:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTR{serial}=="314839673237", RUN+="/usr/bin/su daniel -c '/home/daniel/bin/betaflight-configurator'"
```

/home/daniel/bin/betaflight-configurator:

```
#!/bin/bash

export DISPLAY=:1
/opt/betaflight/betaflight-configurator/betaflight-configurator
```

The way I understand it is that the GUI app has difficulties starting, since it's not starting in the context of the X server.
Still, running the code from another tty opens the app perfectly fine.

What can I improve to make the app run upon plugging in my USB device?

Comment: (i) Did you check that your rule is actually executed ? You can do so by replacing your `RUN+="..."` block with `RUN+="echo $(date) > /home/daniel/udev_exec.log"` for instance. (ii) I would actually look at ADDITIONAL filtering on action with ACTION=="add" placed before your `RUN+="..."` block. That would restrict the trigger condition to you plugging-in your serial device. (iii) Also report if `"/home/daniel/.Xauthority"` exists in your home directory... --- There are other issues but you can start with that. Please report by editing your OP.

Answer (score 0):

You should not start any long running programs from udev rules -- udevd will kill them after a short while, EVEN if you try to run them in background (with `&` from a script). It will also put other roadblocks in their way.

A non recommended hack could be to install the `atd` daemon and start them with `echo some_command | at now`. You will find plenty of examples of that online.

What you should actually do depends on what kind of system you have -- with a "modern" you will have no way but learn how to use systemd (shudder).

Comment: Thanks, I am quite familiar with systemd. So, would it make sense to launch my gui app as a systemd service?

Comment: Probably yes. If it's an input device, it would make more sense to start the app via the X11 input extension, which doesn't need any root privileges (search for inputplug)

Comment: @DanielD. I beg to differ if only on principle. `systemd` places each service in its own session to ensure a clean execution environment for the service (see `man 7 daemon`). In addition it doesnot restrict execution privileges in any way. So starting a gui app as a "service would be the equivalent of daemonizing its execution, something you probably don't need/want to do, not to mention the execution privileges tacked on that "service".